# Register External tool in Power BI Desktop without admin rights

Tags: powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I am working on computer without admin rights. I am not able to install software nor alter installed one. But fortunately, I was able to install Power BI Desktop from Microsoft Store without problems.

Now I want to register some tools mentioned here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jScicVBrr0s. With the help of this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-external-tools-register it should be matter of copying JSON file. But the directory of the application from app store is restricted to me.

Is there a chance, that mentioned `/External Tools` folder can be created in user data space and still loaded by Power BI Desktop on start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It seems not to be possible to register tools without administrative permissions**. I could not find settings to change the location of the data.

It is possible to change the install location with command line but these options only apply to .msi and .exe installations. This still needs administrative permissions

You should ask your IT to do this for you.
If you can download Power BI from Microsoft Store the IT allowed this.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue. I tried this out, and it seems to be working. You need admin rights one time only to set it up, and then you're fine. This creates a Directory Junction to a folder on any drive.

1. Create a new folder somewhere where you have access without admin rights
2. Then navigate to:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Power BI Desktop
   ```
3. Copy files from `External Tools` folder to folder created in step 1.
4. Delete the `External Tools` folder
5. Open command prompt (CMD)
6. Run this command:

   ```sh
   mklink /j "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Power BI Desktop\External Tools" "path of folder from step 1"
   ```

When tools are installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Power BI Desktop\External Tools`, they will be stored in your new folder. If you need to make changes to the .json files, you will be able to edit them in the new folder.